# Coding web page to display name and link to all files in a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Background story and goal:** I'm working on a script to send files (documents) from server A via ftp to web server B. Then on B I want the asp.net web page to present the name of all the files (somehow visually informing the user of what files are in what folder) and provide a link to that file.

**My question is:** what is a good way to display the content of directories and sub directories by a website using asp.net and C#? Would it work just go through the file structure starting in the uploaded root directory or should I modify the script to generate and send a xmlfile over the folder structure and then use the XmlDataSource? How would I set the data path for the XmlDataSource to ensure that it would use the uploaded xml file?

> *Note:* I believe there are some concurrency issues with both. But I believe that's a separate stackoverflow question.

Comment: Why not just allow [Directory Browsing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725840(WS.10).aspx) via IIS settings?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, I think that may cause some security issues.

Comment: I think @shadow wizard should promote his comment to an answer, using <location> <authorization> in the web.config would get around any security concerns.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Smart! That would be a quick and easy solution. But it isn't pretty (from a view and navigation perspective) so I'm unsure of it as an final solution. And I'm unsure if the server admin would agree to make that change. But I will try to make this available during development.

Comment: To make it pretty, you can use jQuery and AJAX.. first Google result: http://riderdesign.com/articles/Build-a-file-tree-explorer-with-jQuery-and-ASP.NET.aspx so maybe it's worth a try.. (demo: http://riderdesign.com/demos/jqueryfiletree.aspx)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard That's a really cool hack. As I understood from your link one can limit which directories can be view but can I limit <b>who</b> can browse the directories to our users? Wouldn't this make the documents publicly available?

Comment: @Tel yes the code there is pretty basic, but if you have login system in place and already store the logged in user in Session it will be almost trivial to restrict access - let me know and I'll post answer with some sample code based on the code there. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Thank you I would love to see it.

Comment: @Tel sorry for the delay, see my answer now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code found [here](http://riderdesign.com/articles/Build-a-file-tree-explorer-with-jQuery-and-ASP.NET.aspx) you can allow only logged in users to view the folder contents. Assuming you store the logged in user in a Session object, here is the code translated to C# plus the check for logged in user only:

```
string dir = Request.Form("dir");
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dir))
    dir = "/";

if (Session["Logged_User"] == null)
{
    Response.Write("Not Authorized");
    Response.End();
}

System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(dir));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<ul class=\"jqueryFileTree\" style=\"display: none;\">").Append(Environment.NewLine);
foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo di_child in di.GetDirectories())
{
    sb.AppendFormat("\t<li class=\"directory collapsed\"><a href=\"#\" rel=\"{0}\">{1}</a></li>\n",  dir + di_child.Name, di_child.Name);
}

foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
{
    string ext = (fi.Extension.Length > 1) ? fi.Extension.Substring(1).ToLower() : "";
    sb.AppendFormat("\t<li class=\"file ext_{0}\"><a href=\"#\" rel=\"{1}\">{2}</a></li>\n", ext, dir + fi.Name, fi.Name);
}
sb.Append("</ul>");
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This wasn't what I expected but this might just be even better.

Comment: I think using `TreeView` controll may be clear and more readable

Comment: Cheers Teletha! @Miro - might be, but it will need lots of customization to style it properly anyway..

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way is using file structure starting from the directory where you uploaded your files(not from root directory).You can save the path of that directory in your `web.config` file in `<AppSettings>` section, then read its structure using `File` and `Directory` classes.

in `web.config`

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="UploadDirectory" value="~/Upload/"/>
</appSettings>
```

In code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string DirectoryName = Request.MapPath(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadDirectory"]);
        if (Directory.Exists(DirectoryName))
        {
            String[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryName);
            myRepeater.DataSource = Files;
            myRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }

}
protected void myRepeater_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        LinkButton FileName = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("FileName");
        String fullName = (String)e.Item.DataItem;
        FileName.Text = fullName.Substring(fullName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
        FileName.CommandArgument=fullName.Substring(fullName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
    }
}
protected void myRepeater_OnItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName=="GOTO")
    {
        Response.Redirect(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadDirectory"]+(String)e.CommandArgument);
    }
}
```

in aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" OnItemDataBound="myRepeater_OnItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
             <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="FileName" CommandName="GOTO"></asp:LinkButton></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but could you please explain your suggestion in a little more detail or perhaps provide a link that does? I've been reading msdn and I'm still unsure how this would be applied.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wish I could give both the accepted answer. I liked your solution and while I didn't get it to work as intended directly I've learnt from it and I will continue to hack on it during the week.